# Create a VARCHAR BINARY column in MySQL with Entity Framework Codefirst

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application that is using EntityFramework Code First to create the database if it doesnt exist. And Im using MySQL for the database engine.

I have a table where one of the Key columns needs to be Case-Sensitive. I dont want to mark the entire database or table as case-sensitive using collation, so the best way to do it (that I know of) is to mark the column as **BINARY**.

Does anyone know how to do this using Code First? I tried doing:

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar(100) BINARY")]
```

but it doesn't like that, the first time I access the DB Model I get

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Sequence contains no matching element

Maybe I should just do an **ALTER TABLE** after the database is created?

Answer (score 1):

> I dont want to mark the entire database or table as case-sensitive using collation

Well, no, that doesn't make sense, but you should be able to do it on the column, using an appropriate collation, e.g.:

```
VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Or just...

```
VARBINARY(100)
```

...is perfectly valid in MySQL (though I have no idea about whether EF will handle it correctly).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: I had actually tried this after I posted the question, unfortunately it does not work in my case because I need the EF property to be a string but this column type is only compatible with byte[]

Comment: Well, if it's binary, then it isn't a string -- it's bytes -- so that part makes sense in a strongly-typed environment.  What about `VARCHAR(100) COLLATE utf8_bin`?  That should be a case-sensitive string.

Comment: That works fine if Im creating the table manually, but Im looking for a way to do it using EntityFramework

Comment: Possibly -- "you can't" -- random google find: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2779 may or may not be applicable.  From my perspective as a DBA, ORMs are generally really good at making simple things difficult or impossible. The notion that this "isn't a very common requirement" strikes me as rather ludicrous, sort of like saying "`VARCHAR` with a length other than 255 isn't a very common requirement."